# Is there shortcut to comment multiline in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

After selecting the lines that needed to be commented out
should click on comment block [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEyE7.png)

Is there any shortcut to select it / uncomment without using mouse ?

Any way to uncomment block with touching the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a default one that I know of, but you can customise the toolbar button(s) so that they show captions as well, and then by prefixing a letter in the caption with an ampersand (eg `Co&mment block`), you can then use Alt+m to trigger it,